# react-bootstrap-table2 how to use multiple datafields in a column

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

```
 const columns = [{
    dataField: 'firstName',
    text: 'Visitor Name'
  }, 
  {
    dataField: 'lastName',
    text: ''
  },];

  <BootstrapTable keyField='id' data={ products} columns={ columns } />
```

Here firstName and lastName should be in one column.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to show multiple data fields in a single Column, you can use **formatter** prop [Formatter function](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/docs/column-props.html#columnformatter-function). It gives you cell and row with which you can easily add multiple datafields in single columns. Here is the working example for you -
[Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-wind-o1rcl?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thank you @dhellryder for the nice code example!